# @FindBy Selenium how to find ::before

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, findby

[::before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjQcD.png)
I have following structure on site and `::before` is checkbox where I'm supposed to click, found some topics, but there was no `@FindBy` annotation. Is it possible to find this ::before in code?

```
<span class="jJ">
<label class="kJ" data-test-id="checkbox_bonus_card">
<input class="mJ" type="checkbox" name="hasBonusCard" value="">
<span data-test-id="checkbox_bonus_card_text" class="lJ">
::before
</span>
</label>
</span>
```

I tried `@FindBy(xpath = "//label[@data-test-id='checkbox_bonus_card'//span['::before']")` but it didn't work.

If I use something like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='hasBonusCard']")
WebElement checkboxBonusCard;
```

Error appears:

```
Caused by: ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <input class="mJ" type="checkbox" name="hasBonusCard" value=""> is not clickable at point (568, 78). Other element would receive the click: <span class="jJ">...</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in input field that you wanna interact with :

```
@FindBy(name = "hasBonusCard")
WebElement bonusCard;
```

**::**  basically means this  :

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of
> the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an
> element with the content property.

More :

> Since ::after & ::before are a pseudo element which allows you to
> insert content onto a page from CSS (without it needing to be in the
> HTML). While the end result is not actually in the DOM, it appears on
> the page as if it is - you see it but can't really locate it with
> xpath for example

Read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)

Comment: Nope, it's not input unfortunatelly, i'm trying to locate input, but error with click interception appears.

Comment: Can you share the full error stack trace ? and how exactly you are using it the @findBy?

Comment: added info in topic

Comment: okay, that means element is not in Selenium view port. Are you launching the browser in full screen mode ? if No, then launch it it full screen. If yes then where is this element present in the UI ? Do you have to scroll (mouse) to get to see this element ?

Comment: Actually this element is in Selenium view port, browser started in full screen mode. Added screenshot [::before] in topic. This checkbox is visible without hover.

Comment: Can you try with actions class ? Like `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(bonusCard).click.perfrom` - see if that works. There's one more way to click using javascriptexecutor. Try that also.. if nothing works then share page url or page resource.